# Filtering by numerical values in r where dataset is text-based

Tags: r, text, filter, subset, numeric

I'm trying to filter these values when they are greater than *5*, but my given column of data has values expressed through a text form, like so:

```
View(vardata)

C1    Variation
DNA   GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00
RNA   GAU=00.00,GGU=00.90
DNA   TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8
DNA   ATGG=11.5
RNA   GUG=00.05,UGG=00.00
DNA   ATA=00.15,ATG=00.95
```

I sincerely have no clue how to make *R* interpret the values included in that form as numerical ones, so as to filter them.

As I don't need to have specified which code of letters has a value greater than X number, in theory I've been trying to just filter these values through

```
selectedvalues = subset(vardata, c(Variation) > 5)
```

Where I would take only the values where the *Variation* column has a numeric value greater than *5*, where I could get a thing like:

```
View(selectedvalues)

C1    Variation
DNA   GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00
DNA   TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8
DNA   ATGG=11.5
```

As only in these cases there appears a value greater than *5*.

But, like I said, I cannot find a way where *R* would interpret the given values so as to scan them as numbers and not text or characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df1[sapply(str_extract_all(df1$Variation, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"), 
         function(x) any(as.numeric(x) > 5)), ]
#   C1                           Variation
#1 DNA GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00
#3 DNA           TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8
#4 DNA                           ATGG=11.5
```

Comment: OMG this worked like a charm, though I wouldn't be understanding the "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+" part

Comment: @CamilaEigner  Thanks. `[0-9]+` implies one or more digits (0-9), followed by a dot (`\\.`) followed by one ore more digits [0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach using `apply` along with `strsplit`:

```
keep <- sapply(vardata$Variation, function(x) {
    sum(sapply(strsplit(x, ",\\s*")[[1]], function(y) {
        as.numeric(strsplit(y, "=")[[1]][2]) > 5
    })) > 0
})
vardata[keep, ]

C1                           Variation
1 DNA GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00
3 DNA           TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8
4 DNA                           ATGG=11.5
```

The idea behind this approach is to split first by comma:

```
[TGGTTA=00.45, TTGATAA=21.8]
```

Then, we split each of the above two terms a second time on `=`, to extract the actual number.  If a given row have even a single number greater than 5, then we retain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
#\\d* 0 or more digits, \\.? 0 or 1 dot, \\d+ 1 or more digits
df %>% mutate(digits=str_match_all(Variation,'\\d*\\.?\\d+'),
              flag=sapply(digits,function(x)sum(as.numeric(x)>5))) %>% 
              filter(flag>0)

     C1                           Variation                     digits flag
  1 DNA GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00 00.15, 08.11, 00.05, 00.00    1
  2 DNA           TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8                00.45, 21.8    1
  3 DNA                           ATGG=11.5                       11.5    1
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
C1    Variation
DNA   'GT=00.15,TT=08.11,TA=00.05,GA=00.00'
                 RNA   'GAU=00.00,GGU=00.90'
                 DNA   'TGGTTA=00.45,TTGATAA=21.8'
                 DNA   'ATGG=11.5'
                 RNA   'GUG=00.05,UGG=00.00'
                 DNA   'ATA=00.15,ATG=00.95'
                 ", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `stringr`?

Comment: You're a wizard!